# convert long type to dateobject in python ?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a long type like

> 1372415991000

I wanna convert it to a date object, any quick way?

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1372415991000/1000)
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 28, 19, 39, 51)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's a Unix timestamp in milliseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(1372415991000 / 1000)
```